# RESTful HTTP vs. Redis vs. WebSocket

Tags: java, websocket, redis

I want to create Java application that will be called by either another Java application or a Node.js application on the same server.  It's an XML validation service.  Which interface would provide the fastest performance?  RESTful HTTP, Redis, or WebSocket?  If it's a WebSocket, what would be a recommended protocol to use on top of it?

Comment: Not sure if its a vaild comparison Websockets - if your client is a browser, redis - is a database, rest seems to be the only option here

Comment: @6ton, or maybe just sockets.  Redis could work with a pub/subscribe in each direction, but not sure about performance vs. HTTP.